# Http response cannot be deserialized when it's created from test case

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, nunit, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to run this test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class AccountManagementViewModelTests
{
    [Test, BaseAutoData]
    public void OnSync_Should_AddToDatabase_MissingLists(
        [Frozen] Mock<IHttpClientService> httpClientService,
        [Frozen] Mock<IDataStore<AppModel.List>> dataStore,
        List<ApiModel.List> lists,
        AccountManagementViewModel sut)
    {
        // Arrange
        httpClientService
            .Setup(x => x.GetAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = JsonContent.Create(lists)
            });

        // Act
        sut.SyncCommand.Execute(null);

        // Assert
        dataStore.Verify(
            d => d.AddItemAsync(
                It.Is<AppModel.List>(
                    x => lists.Any(y => y.Guid == x.ListId))),
            Times.Exactly(3));
    }
}
```

Problem is, when I try to deserialize the response, I get 3 empty entities

```
var allBackedupListsForCurrentUserRequestTask = _httpClientService.GetAsync(string.Format(ListApiEndPoints.GetListsByOwnerEmail, ApplicationUser.Current.Email));    
var allBackedupListsForCurrentUserRequest = await allBackedupListsForCurrentUserRequestTask;
var allBackedupListsForCurrentUser = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<ApiModel.List>>(await allBackedupListsForCurrentUserRequest.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
```

If I examine the content of `allBackedupListsForCurrentUserRequest.Content` I can see all the data there, but none are deserialized into the `allBackedupListsForCurrentUser`.

The code works fine with real HttpRequests, the issue rises only during unit tests.

What am I missing here?

Other classes involved:

**HttpClientService**

```
using ListApp.Services.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ListApp.Services
{
    public class HttpClientService : IHttpClientService
    {
        private static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string requestUri)
        {
            return await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutAsync(string requestUri, HttpContent content)
        {
            return await _httpClient.PutAsync(requestUri, content);
        }
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string requestUri, HttpContent content)
        {
            return await _httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
        }

        public void SetBaseAddress(Uri baseAddress)
        {
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseAutoDataAttribute**

```
using AutoFixture;
using AutoFixture.AutoMoq;
using AutoFixture.NUnit3;
using System;

namespace ListApp.UnitTests.DataTtributes
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    internal class BaseAutoDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
    {
        public BaseAutoDataAttribute() : base(() => CreateFixture()) { }

        private static IFixture CreateFixture()
        {
            var fixture = new Fixture();

            fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true, GenerateDelegates = true });

            return fixture;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the problem is deserializing, then the only code that should matter is the json returned by `await allBackedupListsForCurrentUserRequest.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()` and the definition of `ApiModel.List`, neither of which you posted.  It may also be helpful to break that line up into separate lines, so you can verify that each one is working as expected

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Jason, it got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm changing the value of `JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` to true when the app starts but not during the tests.

Setting it to true on the `[OneTimeSetUp]` did the trick.

```
    ((JsonSerializerOptions)typeof(JsonSerializerOptions)
                    .GetField("s_defaultOptions",
                        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static |
                        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(null))
                    .PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
```

Solution by [andre-ss6](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31094#issuecomment-543342051).